# Pom.xml file showing error after creating maven project

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

Thanks in advance!
I'm getting pom.xml file error after creating maven project.
Error:
Could not calculate build plan:Plugin
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved :Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.pluguns:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.11.0

Tried with adding new dependencies and and all but not resolved yet and this error getting after formatting my machine

Comment: Failed to read artifact descriptor for `....pluguns...`? should be `plugins`